# basic C++ syntax: why is the namespace used before the variable name but not before the class type

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and wading thru the [flightgear](http://www.flightgear.org/) source code. I understand that you can restrict the [type](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) of a pointer, like this

```
CRectangle * prect;   //prect is a pointer that must point to an object of type CRectangle
```

I also understand that you can refer to a variable in a [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/), like this:

```
 cout << first::var << endl;   //prints value of var in namespace = first
 cout << second::var << endl;  //prints value of var in namespace = second
```

With that said, I am trying to understand this line of code in the flightgear codebase:

```
FGKeyboardInput * FGKeyboardInput::keyboardInput = NULL;
```

It seems like it is creating a pointer called keyboardInput of type FGKeyboardInput. But I am confused about what the namespace declaration before keyboardinput is doing. Is that declaring the variable keyboard input as part of the namespace FGKeyboardInput? In the linked namespace tutorial, you declare a variable as part of a certain namespace by including it within namespace brackets. Is the above code a sort of short-hand for something like this?

```
namespace FGKeyboardInput
{
  FGKeyboardInput * keyboardInput = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a namespace and not the definition of a static data member?

Comment: @juanchopanza no, how would I find that out?

Comment: Read about the scope resolution operator `::` it could not be a namespace here.

Comment: You would look at the place where `keyboardInput` is declared.

Comment: You've already established that `FGKeyboardInput` is a type, not a namespace, so the answer to your question is that it's a type, not a namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ symbol names have a scope and a visibility. If you define a data type in a namespace then the symbol name is visible only in that namespace. To be able to use that symbol name in your current scope you need to import that symbol name. There are number of ways to do that:

- Use the fully qualified name of the symbol. i.e: `namespaceName::symbolName` or
- Use [using declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/was37tzw.aspx) or
- Use [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3.aspx).

So when you use:

```
cout << first::var << endl;
```

It means refer to the `var` which resides in the namespace `first`. Note that it could also mean refer to `var` which resides in a class\structure ***if*** it is a static member.

Having said above,

```
FGKeyboardInput * FGKeyboardInput::keyboardInput = NULL;
```

Seems to be definition of a static data member pointer named `keyboardInput` inside the class\structure named `FGKeyboardInput` and it is pointer to the type `FGKeyboardInput`.

Comment: That was really helpful. I think you are correct. But I am still wondering: why do you need the part that says "FGKeyboardInput *"? I am familiar with VB/C# where you would just need to do something like FGKeyboardInput.keyBoardInput = Nothing. (ie. FGKeyboardInput::keyboardInput = NULL;). What is the FGKeyboardInput *  doing?

Comment: @abe3, you already answered that part yourself: _"It seems like it is creating a pointer called keyboardInput of type FGKeyboardInput"_.  `FGKeyboardInput*` is the type of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

> I also understand that you can put a variable in a namespace, like this:

That's not how you *put* a variable in a namespace, that's how you *refer* to a variable which was already put in a namespace.

> It seems like it is creating a pointer called keyboardInput of type FGKeyboardInput.

Right.

> But I am confused about what the namespace declaration before keyboardinput is doing. Is that declaring the variable keyboard input as part of the namespace FGKeyboardInput?

No. That's not a *declaration* of anything, the name before the `::` is a scope, which might be a namespace, but in this case it's not. You've already established that `FGKeyboardInput` is a type, and type names can be scopes.  What you're looking at is the definition of a static data member, which was declared something like this:

```
class FGKeyboardInput
{
public:
    static FGKeyboardInput* keyboardinput;
};
```

That defines a class, `FGKeyboardInput`, and declares a static data member of the class, `keyboardinput`. The static data member must be defined somewhere in the program, which is done like this:

```
FGKeyboardInput * FGKeyboardInput::keyboardInput = NULL;
```

In this case the `FGKeyboardInput::` part refers to something that was declared in the scope of the `FGKeyboardInput` class.  You use similar syntax to define a member function that was declared in a class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int func();   // declare member function
};

int Foo::func()   // define member function
{
    // ...
}
```

To define the member function you must qualify it with the name of the class it is a member of, i.e. `Foo::func`.

> Is the above code a sort of short-hand for something like this?

No, there is no such shorthand, to declare a member of a namespace you must open the namespace and declare the member inside, you cannot add things to a scope using the `::` operator, you can only refer to things that are already declared in that scope.